# Unwanted creation of object at same memory address

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory

I haven't been working with C++ for a long time and now I need to do some small "project".
I reviewed few topics trying to find solution for my problem with no results...

Here is "pseudo-code" (`Pair` is my class):

```
Pair** pairs;
```

I get size of table from input and create table of pointers:

```
pairs = new Pair*[size];
```

I have a loop which creates some object and puts it's reference into table of pointers. More or less:

```
while (...)
{
    Pair pair(...); // calling constructor, creating object type of Pair.
    pairs[i] = &pair;
    i++;
}
```

The **problem** is that `&pair` is the same number everytime (every step of loop).
Let's say the address of first created object is 1234.
So with every step in loop it overrides this object at 1234. So each pointer in `pairs` points to the same address -> same object.
I would like to force creating this object at new place in memory.

I've been trying to put those objects into other table and then pass their reference to table of pointers:

```
Pair* clearPairs = new Pair[size];
while (...)
{
    clearPairs[i] = Pair(...);
    pairs[i] = &clearPairs[i];
    i++;
}
```

But problem still occurs.

Any tips?, mistakes/errors in my code (or thinking)? Shall I implement some "copying constructor"?

Comment: aren't you taking an address of local in while loop.
prefer creating new object on heap each time you loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while (...)
{
    Pair pair(...); // calling constructor, creating object type of Pair.
    pairs[i] = &pair;
    i++;
}
```

`pair` is allocated with automatic storage duration and goes out of scope upon each iteration of the loop.  You are saving a pointer to an invalid object (a bunch of them).

You should use a collection of smart pointers if you *really* need pointers (this is true when objects cannot be copied or copies are expensive), which may not be necessary at all. Try this instead:

```
vector<Pair> pairs;
// and if you need pointers...
vector<unique_ptr<Pair>> pairs;

while(whatever) {
    pairs.push_back(Pair(...));
    // or...
    pairs.push_back(unique_ptr<Pair>(new Pair(...)));
}
```

Comment: Okay, but I still don't know why it's wrong when I put this `pair` object into separate table?

Comment: and assuming that Pair is similar to `std::pair`, I.E. a key and a value you could use `std::map` as well - but i'm guessing here. Eds answer is a good one.

Comment: I think when using vector I can't access object at specific position (I.E. pairs[3]). The task is to implement heap, so I would rather need that option (as well as assigning NULL to element in table). But I might be wrong...

Comment: You can use std::vector just like an array and access pairs[3], for example. Also, you can add NULL elements. Anyway, if you just need to add a fixed number of items, you may use an array too

Comment: @Daniel Castro, thanks. I was just doing some research on vector and also found that info ;). Unfortunately, size of an array is dynamic (user enters the size).

Comment: Then you can use std::vector.. It automatically adapts its size when you're adding items (you add items using push_back method, as Ed S. points in the answer)

Comment: @bart.z33: You can also call `vector::reserve` if you know the minimum required size up front.  This prevents unnecessary allocations/copies later on.